# DocuSign Visual Studio Extension not returning access token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, docusignapi, e-signature, net-4.7.2

My new web apps `(ASP.NET MVC, .Net Framework 4.7.2)` could not find `DocuSign.eSign.dll` references to invoke SDKs even though I verified the dll is installed leading to failure in obtaining access token.

> [image]

I am following exact steps listed on [DocuSign Visual Studio extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension&ssr=false#overview)
I selected only "Embeded sending" code-exaple to be part of my project.

**High level view of steps I need to take to run DocuSign “Embaded Signing” code example.**

> [image]

**Errors I am getting while taking steps 1 to 4:**

- File Names - FilterConfig.cs & DSOWinStartup.cs
- `DocuSign namespace do not recognise eSign or eSignature`
- *Corrective action tried without success* – eSignature reference were replaced with eSign, it still did not recognise eSign or objects within that namespace.

> [image]
> [image]

**Errors I am getting while taking steps 5:**

- File Names - HomeController.cs & Web.config
- Added step 5 code in "About"

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

**URL value when I go to "About" page**

> https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?client_id=<client_id>&
> scope=signature%20impersonation%20&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44333%2F%2Fds%2FCallback&state=Tn9JX2kfRMIu1aty5-AqEQ7jv9OVYNTDK5n8sHs0dig0j5vyzeIVmJ-RJ64wJggQYW5unqD2BuqiDz6NgiNPsNF0EpIaLZZ5bun2hK2LGYc

**DocuSign Admin account settings**

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

https://localhost:44333//ds/Callback

(note that it's not https://localhost:44333/ds/Callback, but to be on the safe side - add both)

To the list of redirectURIs

that's the one you are actually trying on your local machine

Comment: Thanks @Inbar, I added three urls in `DocuSign App`, they are  `https://www.example.com/ds/callback | https://localhost:44333/ds/Callback | https://localhost:44333//ds/Callback`. At-least I got a challange prompt from DocuSign that `<My App> is Requesting Permission` and click on `Allow Access`. This brought AccessCode in URL. This is very helpful to atleast be able to resolve one issue of getting access token in my web app. Thanks a lot

Comment: Next, I need to save `Access Token` in my code env. Step#5 is doint it like below
 `if (RequestItemsService.Instance.User == null)
              return new DSChallengeResult();
 accessToken = RequestItemsService.Instance.User.AccessToken;
`
However `RequestItemsService.Instance.User` is always getting `null` and taking control back to webpage without saving `Access Token`. Any thoughts how I could ensure `RequestItemsService.Instance.User` returns a `user`?